# How to give background color to hl-todo-keywords?

Tags: highlighting

I am using following setup in my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq hl-todo-keyword-faces
      '(("TODO"   . "#FF0000")
        ("FIXME"  . "#FF0000")
        ("DEBUG"  . "#A020F0")
        ("GOTCHA" . "#FF4500")
        ("STUB"   . "#1E90FF")))
```

Here all those keywords shown as bold and as their defined color.

In addition to that, I want to provide yellow background highlight color to all. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [doc string of `hl-todo-keyword-faces`](https://github.com/tarsius/hl-todo/blob/3bba4591c54951d2abab113ec5e58a6319808ca9/hl-todo.el#L106-L145) says:

> Each entry has the form (KEYWORD . COLOR).  KEYWORD is used as
>   part of a regular expression.  If (regexp-quote KEYWORD) is not
>   equal to KEYWORD, then it is ignored by `hl-todo-insert-keyword'.
>   Instead of a color (a string), each COLOR may alternatively be a
>   face.

So `COLOR` can also be a face.
You can define your own faces with `defface`.

Example:

```
(defface hl-todo-TODO
  '((t :background "#f0ffd0" :foreground "#ff0000" :inherit (hl-todo)))
  "Face for highlighting the HOLD keyword.")
```

- The `hl-todo-TODO` is the face name which you can put into `hl-todo-keyword-faces` instead of the color string `"#FF0000"`.
- The third arg of `defface` is the face specification which is an alist that maps terminal types to attributes. Use `t` as terminal type if you do not care.
- Behind the `t` the property list with the face attributes starts. You can inherit from face `hl-todo` and set your own foreground and background color.
- The last arg of `defface` is the doc string for the face.

Comment: I have added the code on the example but it didn't help

Comment: Did you also replace `"#FF0000"` with `hl-todo-TODO` in `hl-todo-keyword-faces`?